How to add dynamic fields to a Symfony form
I have a Symfony 7 form where I have a button called addOption. When clicked, I want to create two input fields to the form. Users can add and delete multiple fields. I have looked into the FormEvents but doesn't seem to work.
Code is pretty much the standard form. I have created a QuestionType extending AbstractType and a model with the same fields.
I think there will be some javascript involved but I just can't figure out the whole flow.
See the attached image for clarification. [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iLl9Zwj8.png

You probably need to use Symfony's CollectionType.

Can you explain a bit?

It sounds like you to want to allow users to dynamically add fields to/remove fields from your form. The Symfony CollectionType allows you to do this, check out the documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/7.1/form/form_collections.html
